# Subsite not inheriting styles from parent masterpage in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

> Hi All,
>   am included few custom styles in parent master page ( styles belings to adjust top navigation). in subsite am inheriting masterpage from parent site, but the styles are not applying or styles are not getting in subsite.
>   how to achive this once to resolve my issue. 
>   this is my subsite  masterpage settings image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure publishing feature enabled on both the site and site collection levels.

If the problem persists, as a workaround you could download the master page from your site collection and upload it to the subsite, then make it the master page there.